# How to link several tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm a newbie at Database Designing. What I want to do is perform several actions at once.

I have a main `users` table which holds all the data for a user at a website. Then I have a `primary key` as the `user_id` in this table. This `user_id` is also the referred in various other tables.

So, what I want to do is connect all those table data to the main table so that when the main user is deleted from the `users` table then all the data related to that user is also deleted. How can I do that?

I know there is a function of foreign keys somewhere but I'm a really amateur programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this question of value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete

**Highlights**:

Your tables should be set up with foreign keys with `DELETE CASCADE`.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id int unsigned not null primary key,
    name varchar(255) default null
);
CREATE TABLE products (
    id int unsigned not null primary key,
    name varchar(255) default null
);

CREATE TABLE categories_products (
    category_id int unsigned not null,
    product_id int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id),
    KEY pkey (product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```